# How to permanantly change the color scheme of the terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome, themes, colors

I have just installed solarized color scheme for ubuntu gnome terminal. I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/solarized-must-have-color-paletter-for.html).  `eval dircolors ~/.dircolor` - this command s causing problems. When I use this command, it changes the color scheme of the terminal for `ls`. But if I restart the terminal the color scheme goes. What does that command do and how can I keep the preference permanently?

Comment: You should rephrase your question. List all steps that you did.

Comment: i did exactly what was told in the tutorial

Comment: Is there a new profile in gnome-terminal?

Comment: no, just the default

Comment: Edit the file `src/set_theme_default_profile.sh` and paste the line `echo "### $PROFILE"` at the end of the file. Post the output here.

Comment: which src folder?

Comment: In the folder gnome-terminal..., cloned from git. And run `set_dark` again.

Comment: ### Default - this is the output

Comment: Ok, thank you. :) Give me more time. I've got to go sleep.

Comment: ok, i've got go to sleep too

Comment: so you want to alter only ls colors permanently or you want everything changed, including text color ?

Comment: `eval dircolors ~/.dircolor` – place this in your `~/.bashrc` to be run every time you open a new shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps I have used:

```
$ cd gnome-terminal-colors-solarized
$ ./install.sh

This script will ask you which color scheme you want, and which Gnome Terminal profile to overwrite.

Please note that there is no uninstall option yet. If you do not wish to overwrite any of your profiles, you should create a new profile before you run this script. However, you can reset your colors to the Gnome default, by running:

    Gnome >= 3.8 dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
    Gnome < 3.8 gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal

By default, it runs in the interactive mode, but it also can be run non-interactively, just feed it with the necessary options, see 'install.sh --help' for details.

Please select a color scheme:
1) dark
2) dark_alternative
3) light
#?

#? 1

Please select a Gnome Terminal profile:
1) Standard
#?

#? 1

You have selected:

  Scheme:  dark
  Profile: Standard (:4d4a684a-7388-40db-adf1-6ec6b6f9043d)

Are you sure you want to overwrite the selected profile?
(YES to continue)

(YES to continue) YES
Confirmation received -- applying settings
```

The open the menu <kbd>Edit</kbd><kbd>Profile Settings</kbd> and <kbd>Check your settings</kbd>. It should look something like this (Sorry for the screenshot with German words).

- *Farben* means *Colors*
- *Text- und Hintergrundfarbe* means *Text and background color*
- *Farbpalette* means *Color palette*
- *Integrierte Schemata* means *Built-in schemes*
- *dunkel Solarisiert* means *dark solarized*
- *Solarisiert* means *Solarized*

[image]

Comment: yes i did that. the color scheme for the terminal had been changed but when I use ls, all the folders have the same color

Comment: that's why we need the first part

Comment: but that was not my question

Comment: eval dircolors ~/.dircolor this code does not change the color of the folders permanently

Comment: The colors changed permanently by `set_dark.sh` and/or `set_light.sh`

Comment: it does change the color. but when i close the terminal and open it again, it changes back.

Comment: I know what wrote, i can just look at the top of page

Comment: You should rephrase your question. List all steps that you did.

Comment: (Just a side note: beginning with Ubuntu Vivid, gnome-terminal ships the Solarized theme by default, there's no need to install it separately.)

Comment: the terminal gives me- bash: cd: gnome-terminal-colors-solarized: No such file or directory