# Change the terminal color profile and font size permanently

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, xfce, colors

I'm using `xfce4-terminal 0.6.3` and I want to change the color profile and font size using the GUI (Edit > Preferences > Colors/Appearance).

However, after making the changes, settings do not persist when I restart xfce as I expected. Most of the software we use normally save the preferences when you change it, to that the next time you use the software our preferences are already set.

There is a similar question here: [How to permanantly change the color scheme of the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612954/how-to-permanantly-change-the-color-scheme-of-the-terminal), but I was no able to detect a useful answer there.

There is another similar question here: [Change color scheme for xfce4 terminal manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676428/change-color-scheme-for-xfce4-terminal-manually) . The accepted answer indeed addresses the same problem. However, I was not expecting to do it manually, since keeping the preferences saved should be default.

I'm running Kubuntu 16.

best

Comment: how are you temporarily changing the profile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color scheme for xfce4 terminal manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676428/change-color-scheme-for-xfce4-terminal-manually)

Comment: @Zanna: using the GUI: Edit > Preferences > Presets, for the colors, and Edit > Preferences > Appearence, for the font size.

Comment: @galoget: I looked at this post. However, it refers only to colors, and the there is no direct answer provided for this which should be a very simple problem.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: I've edited the question to address your comment. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use the KDE terminal

Comment: In KDE Terminal, or Konsole, changing color and font size is easy and straightforward. And, as any application, changing settings persist when you restart the system. So, if the fact that settings do not persist in xfce is not a bug, I accept this answer and I'll change my console application.